# Websocket connection closed. An error occurred: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, websocket, wss, web3py

I'm trying to receive pending transactions from the `eth mempool`, for which I use a `wss` connection to the node.

The problem is that when normally receiving messages from the node, no errors occur and the cycle is not interrupted.

however, if I add transaction verification via web3, after a couple of minutes of the software running, an error occurs.

In websocket:

```
ERROR:root:An error occurred: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

and in websockets:

```
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ConnectionClosedError(None, None, None)>
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: no close frame received or sent
```

websocket code:

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    timing = time.perf_counter()
    try:
        if 'eth_subscription' in message:
            tx = json.loads(message)
            try:
                tx = web3.eth.get_transaction(tx['params']['result'])
                print(tx)
            except TransactionNotFound:
                pass
            #Thread(target=get_tx, args=(tx_hash,)).start()
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
    finally:
        print(colored(str(time.perf_counter() - timing), 'magenta'))


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Opened connection")



def main():
    try:
        websocket.enableTrace(True, level='INFO')
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:7546", on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error,
                                    on_close=on_close,)

        subscribe_request = {
                        "id": 1,
                        "method": "eth_subscribe",
                        "params": [
                            "newPendingTransactions"
                        ],
                        "jsonrpc": "2.0"
                    }
        ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel, reconnect=5, sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
        ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_request))
        rel.signal(2, rel.abort)
        rel.dispatch()
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {err}")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

websockets code:

```
async def get_event():
    async with websockets.connect(node_ws_url, ping_timeout=None) as ws:

            await ws.send('{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newPendingTransactions"]}')
            subscription_response = await ws.recv()
            print(subscription_response)

            while True:
                try:
                    message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=60)
                    #print("Received message:", message)
                    response = json.loads(message)
                    txHash = response['params']['result']
                    tx = web3.eth.get_transaction(txHash)
                    print(tx)
                except TransactionNotFound:
                    pass
                except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as e:
                    logging.error(f"Connection closed: {e}")
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(get_event())
```

Comment: could you please refactor  your question?

Comment: Are you sure about this  part of code? :
```await ws.send('{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newPendingTransactions"]}')``` 
it seems that you are sending a json file in format of string

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37661778/15809896

Comment: @AkramBENGHANEM, thank you. but it just working fine, the subscription works and for the first couple of minutes I receive messages from the node perfectly without any failures. but if the code also contains web3.eth.get_transaction() - after a couple of minutes the socket is disconnected